# XCode hangs for about 10 seconds when saving

Tags: xcode, osx-lion, xcode4.2

I just installed XCode 4.2 and I am running Lion 10.7.2. The problem is that when I try to save a file it usually works fine to save the first one or two times. Then XCode hangs/freezes for about 10 seconds as soon as I try to save.

First I blamed my SSD drive, but it seams to have TRIM enabled and all permissions etc. in order.

This is of course very frustrating. Anybody else who is suffering from the same issue? Any solutions?

Comment: what does a sample show?

Comment: happens to me all the time, super annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check your virus scan. I had Kaspersky running. Shutting it down solved all the problems with XCode!

Comment: Wow. You are right. This will save me hours the next month ;-) I never expected this.

Comment: Any idea what the problem with having an antivirus scanner running when saving in Xcode might be?